# Using null value in case null or empty clob

Tags: oracle, clob

I have question regarding the setting of clob value to null vs setting empty.
My understanding is setting as a null will reduce the storage in db (like lob pointers)
Is there any way that i can track size of lob pointers in oracle and will there be performance benefits by setting null against setting blank

Comment: If you are using CLOBs why are you worried about the minimal difference in bytes between a `NULL` (unknown) value and an `EMPTY_CLOB()` string with zero length? Surely the driving force between choosing one or the other should be on the semantic meaning ("unknown" vs "known but empty") rather than if you use X vs Y bytes in storage.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the size in Bytes of a clob you can use the next example:

```
select DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(x) clonLenInBytes
from example
```